# What kind of vessel is suitable for storing and aging eggnog?

Tags: eggs, storage-method

I am planning on making eggnog for the first time. I am from Australia where eggnog is not really a thing, and living in the UK where that still seems to be the case. This means I haven't grown up seeing how eggnog gets prepared and stored.

I am aware that some recipes of eggnog are made to be stored and aged for a week or more, sometimes a month or even several months. I plan to make some tomorrow to have on boxing day (so 14 days). If I were to make eggnog to be consumed in a day or two I imagine I'd just store it in a plastic jug, but what should I be using if I were to store it for longer?

[The eggnog recipe on Alton Brown's website](https://altonbrown.com/eggnog-recipe/) mentions storing it in glass jars. Should I be using mason jars, or jam jars with screw-on lids, or is either fine? Are there better/worse answers?

Comment: I use a 2-quart mason jar that I've had in the fridge since Thanksgiving. Every couple of days I take it out, shake it a bit, and turn it over (so it spends half its time upside-down). Do note that it's important for the mix to be 20% alcohol to be safe to age.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, look at how the professionals do it: Use the vodka bottle that'll be empty by the time the eggnog is ready to be poured into a container.

Jam jars are easier if you don't have a funnel handy, but depending <s>how much of an alcoholic you are</s> on the alcohol content of your eggnog, you could use the proverbial chalice found in the basement of your castle and just give it a fast wipe-down with a 100 year cloth as it contains so much alcohol it'll sterilise said chalice.

<sub><sup>Personally, I use my left-over eggnog to strip paint off walls.  **;-) 0:-)**</sup></sub>

Answer (score 2):

I made a double batch of Alton Brown's aged eggnog in July. It's been sitting in several 32 oz mason jars and tastes great when I sneak a sip every few days. I didn't fill them all the way (so the nog doesn't contact the lids at all, except when I shake it up right before serving)

https://altonbrown.com/eggnog-recipe/ he suggests a "large glass jar"